# acquiretokenasync not returning to call onactiveresult

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, active-directory

I am new to Xamarin and there was a sample windows desktop application of active directory authentication which I am trying to create in xamarin android. I am using Xamarin netstandard 2.0 project. I tried to find too much for ADAL sample app in .netstandard 2.0 but all I was getting was portable xamarin app.

Below is my code -

```
 protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
     SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
     Button btnActivate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnActivate);
     if (btnActivate != null)
     {
         btnActivate.Click +=  (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
         {
              btnActivate_Click(sender, e);
              FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnActivate).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
         };
     }
 }

private async void btnActivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(commonAuthority);
        if (context.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
            context = new AuthenticationContext(context.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);

            result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
                graphResourceUri,
                clientId,
                new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:-Oauth:2.0:-Oob"),
                new PlatformParameters(this), 
                UserIdentifier.AnyUser, 
                "nux=1");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          //this.mainForm.Log(ex.ToString());
     }
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Above is the code I am using for Active Direcotry authentication, I am able to view microsoft's login page but after applying credential and signing in I did not get any response neither the execution go to OnActivityResult mehtod.

As I said I am new to xamarin with very less knowledge of it please help me to know if I am missing anything.

One more thing please note that above code is using netstandard 2.0 library.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a [Xamarin sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget) that uses [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/ADAL.NET-supports-multiple-application-architectures-and-multiple-platforms) for authentication. I think you will find it useful as a jumping off point.